# Why is this piece of Javascript giving a parse error?

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var flashvars = { file: ’foo’, autostart: ’true’ };
</script>
```

Throws Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL with the newest Google Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because you don't use proper quotation marks. You use `’` instead of `'` or `"`.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var flashvars = {file: 'foo', autostart: true };
</script>
```

Two more things:

- Don't escape the quotes of the `type` attribute.
- `true` does not have to be in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong kind of apostroph. You write ’foo’ but it must be 'foo'

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var flashvars = { 'file': 'foo', 'autostart': true }; 
</script>
```

Comment: The keys don't have to be in quotes. And just throwing in some code is not particular helpful imo. What do you try to explain that is not already explained in the other answers?